# How to update npm permanently?

Tags: macos, npm, n

I'm trying to update npm from 2.15.11 to 3.9.2 and I manage to do it, but it's not permanent; if I switch Node version, npm goes back to 2.15.11 and if I come back to the Node version in which I updated npm, npm is also back to 2.15.11

```
 $ node -v
0.12.18
 $ npm -v
2.15.1
 $ sudo npm i -g npm@3.9.2
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.9.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 $ npm -v
3.9.2                  //SUCCESS! right?
 $ sudo n 0.10.48
 $ npm -v
2.15.1                 //nope
 $ sudo n 0.12.18
 $ npm -v
2.15.11                //very nope
```

What's missing? Could n be the reason my install isn't permanent?

If it's of any relevance I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` does a full install of `node` *and* `npm`. The upside is you get the pair that shipped together after you change version using `n`, the downside is that it may be a downgrade for `npm`. This is the same outcome as downloading the Mac installer directly from nodejs.org and running.